# Get the index from Array of objects and add it as new property

Tags: angular, indexing

I need to get the index of each object from the array of objects and add it as a new property in the object. Below is my Array of objects

[image]

Below is my angular code regarding the functionality

```
 sub.add(dragEnd.subscribe((e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dataItem = this.popupData[draggedItemIndex];
    dataItem.dragging = false;
    this.keys = [dataItem.attributeLabel];
    console.log(this.popupData);
    this.popupdataEmitter.emit(this.popupData);
  }));
```

So, the popupData is the content of a grid and I need to set a new property called "rowOrder" to pass it to an API. How do I can add a new property based on the index? Please suggest.

Comment: `this.popupData[draggedItemIndex].rowOrder = "newAttribute"` - if you are struggling to get the index `ngFor` has a feature for this `ngFor="let x of array; let i = index"`

Answer (score 0):

This line should do the thing:

```js
this.popupData.forEach((row, index) => row.rowOrder = index)
```

Explenation:
Go through the array and set the index on each row as `rowOrder`.

Note that you set the `rowOrder` on every row object.